# req.isAuthenticated is false and req.user is undefined. How can I solve this?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

Req.isAuthenticated() is returning false after login, and also after registering new user. What do I need to do to fix it?

I have an application which have two different logins. One for "users" and other for "employees". The "user" one was the first that I created, and works perfectly, both the register and login process. 
But the "employee" one does not. I have made its code a mirrored version of the "user", since the "user" one is working fine, but this one is not working properly.

I Created two different strategies for each one (user and employee), and two passport instancies, but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
passport, models and express-session vars config
var passportUser = require("passport");
var passportEmployee = require("passport");
var LocalStrategyUser = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var LocalStrategyEmployee = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var User = require("./models/user");
var Employee = require("./models/employee");
var session = require('express-session');
```

Passport config

```
//PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(session({
    secret: "Mar do macaco",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
    cookie : {
        secure:false,
        expires: false,
    }
 }));


app.use(cookieParser());

//USER
app.use(passportUser.initialize());
app.use(passportUser.session());

passportUser.use('user',new LocalStrategyUser(User.authenticate()));
passportUser.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id);
 });

passportUser.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    cb(null, user);
  });
 });



//EMPLOYEE
app.use(passportEmployee.initialize());
app.use(passportEmployee.session());

passportEmployee.use('employee',new 
LocalStrategyEmployee(Employee.authenticate()));
Employee.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passportEmployee.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
   if (err) { return cb(err); }
    cb(null, user);
  });
});
```

The employee ROUTES for registration and login (not working fine)

```
//REGISTER NEW EMPLOYEE
app.get("/registernew", function(req,res){
    res.render("employeeform")
})

//New Employee register logic
app.post("/registernew", async function(req,res){
    var newEmployee = new Employee({
        username:req.body.username,
        firstname:req.body.firstname,
        lastname:req.body.lastname,
        birth:req.body.birth,
        adress:req.body.adress,
        education:req.body.education,
        experience:req.body.experience,
        role:req.body.role
    });
    Employee.register(newEmployee, req.body.password,async function(err,employee){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.render("employeeform");
        } else{

            console.log("employee registered with success");
        }
        await passportEmployee.authenticate("employee")(req,res,function(){
            console.log("employee logged in");
            console.log(req.user.username);
            res.redirect("/");
        });
    })
})

//Employee Login

app.get("/employeelogin", function(req,res){
    res.render("employeelogin")
})

app.post("/employeelogin", passportEmployee.authenticate("employee",{successRedirect:"/",failureRedirect:"/employeelogin",failureFlash:true,successFlash: 'Welcome!'}),function(req,res){
    console.log(req.user)
})
```

USER routes for Register and login (WORKING PERFECTLY)

```
//show register form
app.get("/register", function(req,res){
    res.render("register");
});

//handle sign up logifc
app.post("/register", function(req,res){
    var newUser = new User({username:req.body.username});
    if(req.body.adminCode === 'secret') {
      newUser.isAdmin = true;
    }
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.render("register");
        }
        passportUser.authenticate("user")(req,res, function(){
            res.redirect("/");
        });
    });
});



//SHOW LOGIN FORM
 app.get("/login", function(req,res){
     res.render("login");
 })

 //handling login logic
 app.post("/login", passportUser.authenticate("user",{successRedirect:"/",failureRedirect:"/login"}),function(req,res){
 })
```

With this, I just want to fix this problem of not being able to be authenticated while using the employee login. It actually do the login, but req.user is undefined and req.isauthenticated is false.

Thank you for the attention

Answer (score 0):

You have to get user data from req.body object before you have to use that. Because its url-encoded data.